# Is there a way to add a table to a Linq-to-SQL dbml in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, scripting, dynamic

I am working on some scripts, and was wondering if anyone knew of a way to dynamically add a table from an MSSQL database into a dbml file, just as if one were to do it the normal "drag-n-drop" way. Is there anything in the framework that allows this?

**Update:**

I have the name of a table, that exists in my database. If it was design time, I could drag the table over from the server explorer and drop it on the Linq to SQL designer, which would add that class. I want to see if there is a way to do this at runtime in code. This very well may not be possible, but it would be very useful for scripting purposes.

Comment: Dynamically how? What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is not possible through SqlMetal which the designer uses. I would recommend that you try http://sqlmetalinclude.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sort of syntax were you expecting?

Comment: @alexn: If I understand correctly, the OP's point is that he does not know the schema at design or compile time. If that's the case, modifying the physical .dbml file won't do much good as the entities will have already been defined and compiled.

Comment: @Adam - I thought that if there was some way to do this, it might be in the form of some sort of API call to the Linq-to-SQL module. It was a long shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible; the point of LINQ-to-SQL (and similar ORM's, like the Entity Framework) is to give you a strongly-typed mechanism for querying and updating your database. If the schema is unknown to you at compile time, then it is impossible to query against it as you could not write code to do so (LINQ-to-SQL *only* allows for expression and LINQ syntax; you cannot hand-craft a query string).

If your schema is unknown to you at compile time, you're better off going with ordinary ADO.NET `DbConnection` and `DbCommand` objects to perform you data manipulation.

Comment: Do you know if Dynamic Linq, where you can handcraft a query string, would make any difference?

Comment: @Prof Plum: If there was some way to modify the .dbml at runtime, probably, but I still question: why? If you have to code the string yourself, what benefit is LINQ-to-SQL giving you? Why not just use the connection and make the command yourself?

Comment: I am working with a pretty large database with several thousand tables, but they all share a similar structure. I got tired of having to integrate each one individually, so I wrote a script that will basically give me some scaffolding to integrate each new table. It can all be done in one simple step now, with the exception of adding the Linq-to-SQL class. It is not really a big deal, but it would have been nice to script that as well.

Comment: @ProfPlum: I don't think I'm clear on what you're doing, are you trying to script the modification of a .dbml file for a project *before* compile time, or *after* compile time?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it will be before. The script will be run, and the script will modify the source of another uncompiled project in development. It autogenerates some code for the project. It would not be meant to make modifications to a live system, but instead is simply a development tool.

Comment: @Prof Plum: In that case, I completely misunderstood your question. You may want to consider rephrasing it, as terms like "dynamically" and saying things like "if it was design time..." imply that you're talking about a *runtime* operation.